# Selecting the particular column to the end in dateframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 15 columns would like to select particular columns (0,3,7 and 8 till 14).

I have tried as below:

```
d = df.iloc[:,[0,3,7]]
dfr = df.iloc[:, 8:-1]
```

Separately, I can able to extract the selected columns.
Now , I am trying to combine but have ended with errors.

I am pleased to hear some suggestions.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I have tried,  df.iloc[:,np.r_[0,3,7,8:-1]]. But, the columns [8:-1] are not included at the output.

Comment: try `df.iloc[:,np.r_[0,3,7,8:len(df.columns)]]`

Comment: Thank you ver much.